# Guardar Imagen en base 64

Tags: android, asp.net, webservice

Quiero que en mi aplicativo pueda seleccionar una imagen y esta se guarde en mi base de datos de sql server, me dijeron que para esto debia convertirla a base 64, estoy usando un web service que cree en ASP.Net en c#, como hago para almacenar mi imagen en mi base de datos?

Comment: te comento nadamás, al generarlo en string base64 y mandarlo por POST a tu webService de ASP.NET, es muy probable que la cadena sea tan larga que no responda.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo entonces cual es tu recomendacion?

Comment: Hola Cesar, has intentado algo, por que no agregas el código? Recuerda que este tipo de preguntas se consideran "demasiado amplias" te sugiero revisar [ask]. Si deseas preguntar de esta forma puedes realizarlo en el [chat], ya tienes la reputación suficiente.

Comment: existen diversas API en internet que te pueden ayudar a realizar lo que deseas, en lo personal, utlizo la API de imgur, y guardo en base de datos la URL donde se encuentra mi imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tendrías que tener es una variable que acepte cadenas gigantes en tu base de datos como los **BLOB** (Binary Large Objects - en ingles), yo trabaje con uno como este:

```
[imagen] varbinary(max) NULL,
```

Esto claro al momento de crear tu base de datos.

Ahora tu código en `C#` para extraer seria algo así:

```
string base64String="";
using (Image imagen = Image.FromFile("la path de tu imagen"))
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imagen.Save(m, imagen.RawFormat);
        byte[] Bytes = m.ToArray();
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Bytes);
    }
}
```

Y pues posterior a eso almacenas `base64String` como cualquier otro dato

Comment: Muchas gracias por respoder, entiendo que el codigo que me muestras en c# es para mostrar la imagen a la hora de consumir el WebService en android, para enviarla a la base de datos solo tendria que tener una variable en android que guarde todo el string de la imagen y lo envie al query de insert en mi WebService?

Comment: No decias que tenias que enviar a android pero basicamante **si** es como dices : ***para enviarla a la base de datos solo tendria que tener una variable en android que guarde todo el string de la imagen y lo envie al query de insert en mi WebService***